# Remove item from NavigationBar Items stack

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

Basic I need to delete items from NavigationBar items Stack

More Details:
I have such a hierarchy of views: A -> B -> C -> B, "->" indicates that segues between views.
I am using NavigationBar for navigating between views.
I would like that when user goes from view C going to B there would be Back button which navigates user to View A instead of View C.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that **A** is your `rootViewController` of `navigationBarController`.
So you can make your own `backButton` in **B Class** then on that button clicked just write -

```
   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pop to first view controller through

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and if you want to pop to a specific viewcontroller of navigationController just do this

```
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

this will pop to 2nd viewController of navigation controller(if any)